# How to put embedded image within width of text block

Tags: html, css

I mostly don't use html\css in my professional life, but for now I have a task that requires some work with markdown.

I have a text which should be no more than 80 character width. Here is a css:

```
.content {
    width: 80ch;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

I want to embed the image like this one:

```
<img src="https://ucarecdn.com/4922ea06-6240-4be5-bd43-06021daa81d4/accountcredentials.png">
```

If I apply it simply within the same div image would go beyond borders (it has bigger width)

How can I put image within width of text block?

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="centered">
    <p class="content">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p class="img">
    <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/4922ea06-6240-4be5-bd43-06021daa81d4/accountcredentials.png">
    </p>
</div>
```

```
.centered {

}

.content {
    width: 80ch;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean like that?

```css
.content {
    width: 80ch;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img  {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
    <p class="content">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <img  src="https://ucarecdn.com/1d0fc207-9d61-4bf3-8e74-a273f1b4ce91/accountcredentials.png">
    </p>
</div>
```

Image inside the `p` tag and `width: 100%`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47rLutw8/)

Comment: Yes, It works. At least for current use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the image as a background.

```
.content {
    width: 80ch;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image: url('https://ucarecdn.com/4922ea06-6240-4be5-bd43-06021daa81d4/accountcredentials.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can then apply **padding** to the class to add spacing around the text, and the borders of the background.

Comment: It can't be a background and I shouldn't put link into css.

Comment: In that case, just setting a given width (100%) on the img will work, and it will auto scale the height to match! But, then the height will be more than the parent div. Are you saying you can't do it, or don't want to set a background image?

Comment: It shouldn't be background image. I have extended my question with full code snippet. Please give it and try

Answer (score 1):

Set a max-width on the image to prevent it overflowing the container.

```css
.content img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sample. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Could you please verify on your side it works well? I'll extend my question with full code snippet